# Suppose $f$ is defined and differentiable proof.

Tags: calculus, analysis

Suppose $f$ is defined and differentiable for every $x>0$, and  $\lim_{x\to \infty} f'(x)=0$.
Put $g(x)=f(x+1)-f(x)$. Prove that $\lim_{x\to \infty} g(x)=0$

Comment: To get focused answers, it is advisable to indicate effort in your question: what have you tried?  Where are you stuck?  What are you unsure about?  Do you know the definitions of all the concepts involved?

Comment: You keep adding new information in the comments about what your professor said to do or not to do.  This information should really be in the question: otherwise, people keep trying to answer with incomplete information.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:
$$
f(x + 1) - f(x) = \int_{x}^{x+1} f'(s) \; ds,
$$
and $f'(s)$ is "getting smaller" as $s$ increases.

Comment: i am confused because our professor said the derivative use the definition

Comment: sorry, not understanding your comment.

Comment: For each positive $\epsilon$, there exists an $M_\epsilon$ such that
$$
|f'(s)| < \epsilon \quad \mbox{ for } s > M_\epsilon.
$$
Therefore, for $x > M_\epsilon$,
$$
|f(x+1) - f(x)| = \left| \int_{x}^{x+1} f'(s) ds \right| \leq \int_{x}^{x+1} |f'(s)| ds \leq \int_{x}^{x+1} \; \epsilon \; ds.
$$

Answer (score 1):

Need to show: given any positive epsilon, there's a positive M such that |g(x)| is less than epsilon for x beyond M.

So, take an arbitrary positive epsilon. 
By the same limit definition, there exists an "M" such that |f'(x)| is small for x beyond M.

Using the mean-value theorem I think you can show that the same M works for |g(x)| too.

Comment: Yes , our professor mentioned about exactly but I did not understand anything

Answer (score 1):

By the mean value theorem for differentiable functions, for $x>0$ there exists $x< c_{x}< x+1$ such that $g(x)=f(x+1)-f(x)=f'(c_{x})$.

If $x\rightarrow \infty$, then $c_{x} \rightarrow \infty$. Therefore, 
$\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}g(x)=\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}f'(c_{x})=\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}f'(x)=0$

Answer (score 1):

MVT:

$g(x)=f(x+1)-f(x)= f'(t_x) \cdot 1$; where $x <t_x <x+1$.

We have $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} f'(x)=0:$

Let $\epsilon >0$ be given.

There is a $M >0$, real, s.t. for $x >M$:

$|f'(x)| < \epsilon.$

For $x >M$:

Since $g(x)=f'(t_x)$ , where $x <t_x,$ we have

$|g(x)| =|f'(t_x)| < \epsilon,$ i .e

$\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}g(x)=0.$

Answer (score 0):

The proof is simple:

$\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} g(x)=\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} f(x+1)-\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} f(x)$

For large $x$, $x+1 \approx x$, so, by the previous result,

$\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} g(x)=0$

Comment: One has to also prove that $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} f(x)$ exists!